# Where can I find large amount of exe files?

Tags: windows, exe, executable

As part of my research in the university I wrote an application that can iterate over a large amount of `.exe` files, execute each one individually and collect runtime data using Procmon. That data is later runs through a machine learning.

The problem is I need at least 100 `.exe` files, that none of them will be an installation wizard and preferably that none of them will be a virus. :-)

I would also like not to search the internet manually, and that none of the `.exe` files will be a windows application (such as notepad.exe and regedit.exe).

I'd appreciate some ideas on how to collect such large amount of executable files easily or alternatively where to find an online archive of executable files.

Comment: Use some machine learning, like genetic programming to generate some?

Comment: @doctorlove Great sense of humor...LOLZZZ

Comment: 100? That doesn't sound remotely enough for ML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can helps you: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html. You can find about 100 *.exe in CoreUtils package.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that executables started without purpose won't do anything useful, most will just complain about lack of command-line arguments, or open a UI that waits for user input.

So your profiling data will collect the behavior of the program doing nothing, not what it's intended to do.  Such profiling data is worse than useless.

(I would hate for my compiler's profile-guided-optimization to train only on the code that checks number of arguments and prints a usage message to the console!  You may not be working on a compiler, but the principle is the same.)

Answer (score 0):

If you know any programming language you can write a simple program to pause for a random period, say 1-5 seconds, then just duplicate the EXE file 100 times and give them different names.

Edit: Based on needing already made EXE files, there are a number of them in the Windows/System32 directory, it would be a really interesting experiment to run every EXE file in the Windows directory and see what happens to the stability of your computer (I think most of them are protected so they wouldn't be able to do any damage if called from the command line).

Comment: Or write a program to generate program to do that :-)

Comment: Thanks, but I want programs "from the wild", not to write it myself. :-)

Comment: git clone everything on github and run that?

Comment: I did a "dir *.exe" in my Windows/System32 directory and there are 441 exe files in there.  Even if they all didn't work, you could probably find 100 that would perform how you want.

Comment: @RussellChristensen Thank you, I didn't wanted applications that come with windows but I guess I'll have to compromise if I won't find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple C program in VS or any other compiler and built it. It will create an exe file for u in the bin folder. Rename this exe 100x with different names. None of them will installation widzard, or virus(cuz u wrote the C program...he he he)

Comment: Thanks, but I need them to be distinct.

Comment: Write a program that writes a different program and compiles it and renames it.